# Why the icon is not coming in flutter's TextField?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I use any Icon in textField, It is not showing that in TextField. Either Prefix or Suffix

```
TextField(
       decoration: InputDecoration(
       border: OutlineInputBorder(
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(22))),
       hintText: "Enter your E-Mail",
       prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail),
))
```

[Screenshot of the widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WCJD.png)

Comment: what you are using phone or emulator

Comment: tried both, as well as run on browser but same thing

Answer (score 0):

The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
the material Icons class.

`uses-material-design: true`

check if this line is present in you `pubspec.yaml` file